# Only need one relation column in get() laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I only want to **pluck 1** column of relation.

example: If I want **unique names** of authors according to input for Paper table

**Paper has many author is the relation**

```
$paper = Paper::with([
    'author' => function($query) use($request)
    {
       $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '$request->name');
    }

])->pluck('name')->unique();
```

But this simply gives error as name is not recognized as the column of Paper.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @jarlh if it could be solved with DB facade of laravel...

Comment: Do you want an SQL answer?

Comment: Do you only need the author names? Or the papers *and* the author names?

Comment: Only author name

Comment: Can't you just query the `authors` table? `Author::where('name', 'LIKE', $request->name)->pluck('name')->unique();`

Comment: No. Because I want the author names who have actually published a paper so I need to use the Paper model to retrieve Authors

Comment: Use `has()`: `Author::has('papers')->where('name', 'LIKE', $request->name)->pluck('name')->unique();`

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yeah...thnx it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the `authors` table directly and use `has()`:

```php
Author::has('papers')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', $request->name)
    ->pluck('name')
    ->unique();
```